# How to create a table with rowspan using php and array of values

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create a table with rowspan using php and array of values but i am really struggling on to create the below:

```html
    <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Tests</th> 
      <th>Values</th>
      <th>Month</th>  
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="2">January</td>
     <td>Test A</td>
     <td>VAL A</td>
     <td rowspan="2">FEB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Test B</td>
     <td>VAL B</td>  
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

using php arrays of values below i used *print_r()* function to display the array how can i achive to create the above table format using this array of values using php

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [month] => January [tests] => Test A,Test B [values] => VAL A,VAL B [month2] => Feb ) )
```

Comment: Your table is not formatted correctly.

Comment: your `print_r` data does not contain `FEB` - where does that come from?

Comment: @mani print_r updated sorry for the typo mistake

Comment: @Meathanjay i want the table as it is now using the php array values given i want to know how can i use foreach, for loops to achieve such a table format

Comment: @Charles Michel Try my given code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code:

```
<?php //The Array
$arr=array(array(
    'month'     => "January",
    'month2'    => 'Feb',
    'tests'     => "Test A, Test B",
    'values'    => "VAL A, VAL B"
));
?>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Tests</th>
    <th>Values</th>
    <th>Month</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($arr as $item): ?>
        <?php
            $test_break=explode(',',$item['tests']);
            $values_break=explode(',',$item['values']);
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><?php echo $item["month"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $test_break[0]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $values_break[0]; ?></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><?php echo $item["month2"] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $test_break[1]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $values_break[1]; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</tbody>
</table>
```